# Elementary question on quotient group construction

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, proof-explanation, quotient-group

I am going though an introductory proof text book and was hoping if someone could verify/correct my attempt at the following problem :

> Let $(\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt3],+,.)$ where $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt3] \subset\Bbb{R}$ and
>   $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt3]=\{i+j\sqrt3 :i,j \in \Bbb{Z} \}$. Consider the Ideal
>   of the ring given by $I=\{a+b\sqrt3 : 3|a \}$.
>
> Construct and Evaluate the quotient ring $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt3]\text{\I}$.

**Attempt**

(i) The equivalence relation ~$_{I}$ is defined by x ~$_{I}$ y iff $(x-y)\in I$ for all $x,y \in \Bbb{Z}[\sqrt3]$.

(ii) x ~$_{I}$ y

- iff $(x-y)\in I$
- iff $x-y = a+b\sqrt3$
- iff $x-y = 3k + b\sqrt3 \text{ for some } k \in \Bbb{Z}$
- iff $y=x-3k - b\sqrt3 $

(ii)By theorem, x ~$_{I}$ y implies that $[x]=[y]$.

With $y=x-3k - b\sqrt3 $, then

$\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt3]\text{\I}$

- $=\{[x] : x \in \Bbb{Z}[\sqrt3] \}$
- $=\{[x-3k - b\sqrt3] : x \in \Bbb{Z}[\sqrt3] \}$

(iii)By theorem,since I is an ideal of $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt3]$, then $(\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt3]\text{\I}),\bigoplus,\bigodot)$ is also a ring with well-defined binary operations.

Let $h,g \in \Bbb{Z}[\sqrt3]$ ,then $[h]\bigoplus[g]$

- = $[h-3k - b\sqrt3] \bigoplus [g-3l - c\sqrt3]$
- = $[h-3k - b\sqrt3 + g-3l - c\sqrt3]$
- = $[h+g - \sqrt3 (\sqrt3(k+l) + (b+c))]$

..similar procedure for $\bigodot$

Is this what is meant by construction? 
Any help appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to check that the addition and multiplication is well defined no matter which representative you choose for the equivalent classes elements in the quotient ring. You have checked operation is closed  in $(iii)$. So we need to verify that if $[x]$~$[y]$ and $[z]$~$[n]$ then $[x]*[z]=[y]*[n]$.

Comment: thank you for the comment.I thought that constructing q uotient  ring was about specifiying the set and binary operations involved rather than checking that the ring was well-defined? thanks!

Comment: @mathpadawan: I'm not sure I agree. Since $I$ is an ideal, then I'm sure the OP has seen proof that the quotient ring operations will be well-defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you need to get a better idea what the elements of $\Bbb Z\bigl[\sqrt{3}\bigr]/I$ are, before you have a feel for what it looks like as a ring. By definition, the elements of $\Bbb Z\bigl[\sqrt{3}\bigr]/I$ are all equivalency classes of elements of $\Bbb Z\bigl[\sqrt{3}\bigr]$ under the relation $\sim_I$ you mentioned above. However, that doesn't really paint a clear picture, yet.

You're right that for any given $x,y\in\Bbb Z\bigl[\sqrt{3}\bigr],$ we will have $[x]=[y]$ if and only if $x-y=3k+b\sqrt{3}$ for some $k,b\in\Bbb Z,$ but this doesn't use the structure of $\Bbb Z\bigl[\sqrt{3}\bigr],$ at all, so doesn't clarify enough. We can do better! In particular, we know that $x=i_1+j_1\sqrt{3}$ and $y=i_2+j_2\sqrt{3},$ where $i_1,i_2,j_1,j_2\in\Bbb Z.$ Thus, we can conclude that $x\sim_I y$ if and only if the following (equivalent) conditions hold: $$x-y=3k+b\sqrt{3}\textrm{ for some }b,k\in\Bbb Z\\(i_1-i_2)+(j_1-j_2)\sqrt{3}=3k+b\sqrt{3}\textrm{ for some }b,k\in\Bbb Z\\i_1-i_2=3k\textrm{ and }j_1-j_2=b\textrm{ for some }b,k\in\Bbb Z$$ However, since $j_1$ and $j_2$ are integers, then this last one is equivalent to $$i_1-i_2=3k\textrm{ for some }k\in\Bbb Z,$$ meaning that $i_1\sim_{(3)}i_2.$ Since the $j$-values had no effect on the equivalency class, then note in particular that $x\sim_I i_1$ which means that we can choose an integer representative for each equivalency class. The equivalence $\sim_{(3)}$ gives us even more, though!

Given any $i\in\Bbb Z,$ there exists a unique $m\in\{0,1,2\}$ and $n\in\Bbb Z$ such that $i=m+3n.$ In particular, say $i_1=m_1+3n_1,$ so since $$x-m_1=i_1+j_1\sqrt{3}-m_1=3n_1+j_1\sqrt{3}\in I,$$ then $[x]\in\bigl\{[0],[1],[2]\bigr\}.$ Thus, $\Bbb Z\bigl[\sqrt{3}\bigr]/I=\bigl\{[0],[1],[2]\bigr\}.$ At that point, it is much easier to see and talk about what $\oplus$ and $\odot$ look like.

Comment: Thank you Cameron,the book i am using is a general intro to proof book rather than an abstract algebra book,so i suspect my answer will only reflect very fundamental ideas. While the left coset was defined, it was never really used in examples of the type i submitted.  Would you say that my answer makes sense nontheless or is there something wrong with it?

Comment: If you don't have results to back up whether the operations of a quotient ring are well-defined, then it might not be a bad idea to prove that they are. As for your answer, I'd say it is a good start, but that word "Evaluate" makes me think you're supposed to come up with a much simpler construction. I will alter my answer to address these points, and to remove reference to left cosets.

Comment: Thanks again Cameron!

Comment: If you are still here Cameron,I am still a bit unclear about the steps below: [1] You mentioned that the j-values have no effect on the equivalence class. I thought that $x$~$_I$$y$ iff [$i_1$~$_3$ $i_2$ and ($j_1$-$j_2$)=$b$]. Do the choices of j-values not affect whether (x-y)$\e I$ and thereby affect whether $x$~$_I$$y$?

Comment: That's correct. Since the only condition on the $j$-values is that their difference must be an integer (which is true no matter what the integers $j_1$ and $j_2$ might be), then it doesn't impose any restrictions on us.

Comment: Goodness,i was still editing the comment and you already responded!...also could you confirm the following please :[2] Is x-$m_1$ motivated by finding an expression for [x] in $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt3]\text{/I}=\{[x]:x \in \Bbb{Z}[\sqrt3]\}$ such that with $(x-m_1) \in I$$\Rightarrow$$x\text{~}_{m1}$$\Rightarrow$$[x]=[m_1]$ where $[m_1] \in \{[0],[1],[2]\}$ and therefore $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt3]\text{/I}=\{[m_1]:m_1 \in \{0,1,2\}\}$??

Comment: Yes, indeed! The idea is to choose "small," simple representatives for our equivalence classes. Since we need $i_1\sim_{(3)}i_2$ in order for $x\sim_I y,$ then taking the typical representatives for the equivalence classes of $\Bbb Z/(3)$ seemed the natural choice.

Comment: Ok ! Thanks Cameron i think i understand this a bit better now.